# How can I create a custom border on a JavaFX stage?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am trying to create a custom border on `stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);`

It doesn't work and i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

```
// Using Pane to able to customize children
Pane rootPane = new Pane(); 

// my main.css is src/main/resources
rootPane.getStylesheets().add("main.css"); 

// rootPane is the name of the css class
rootPane.getStyleClass().add("rootPane"); 

// creating the scene with the Pane layout.
Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, model.getSceneWidth(), model.getSceneHeight()); 

// Fetch the file with classLoader and add css to the scene.
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("main.css").toExternalForm());

stage.setScene(scene);       
stage.show();
```

And my main.css:

```
.rootPane {
  -fx-border-insets: 23;
  -fx-background-radius: 6;
  -fx-border-radius: 6;
  -fx-border-color: white;
  -fx-border-style: solid;
  -fx-border-width: 5;
  -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(100, 100, 100, 1), 24, 0.5, 0, 0);
  -fx-background-insets: 23;
}
```

Full start method code:

```
@Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {

            matrixStage = stage;
            matrixStage.setTitle("null");
            matrixStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

            Pane rootPane = new Pane();
            rootPane.getStylesheets().add("main.css");
            rootPane.getStyleClass().add("rootPane");

            Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, matrixModel.getSceneWidth(), matrixModel.getSceneHeight());
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("main.css").toExternalForm());

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
            canvas.widthProperty().bind(matrixStage.widthProperty());
            canvas.heightProperty().bind(matrixStage.heightProperty());    

            rootPane.getChildren().add(canvas);
            matrixStage.setScene(scene);
            matrixStage.show();
    }
```

After I set canvas width and height and .bind it with stage property the border disapears. Its because canvas 'covers' the custom border ? and its behind or something ?

Comment: Can you explain "doesn't work"? This works as expected for me (and looks quite nice, btw). Perhaps just expand your code to be a [MCVE].

Comment: I have added some code to make it more visible, maybe canvas have problem with it or something ? i don't know really.

Comment: Maybe that's the problem. Unless you actually post a [MCVE] that demonstrates the issue and that other people can run, though, it's not going to be possible for anyone else to figure it out (or, at least, will take way more work than people will be prepared to put in for free). Just start with a new, minimal, example (say a blank canvas); if that demonstrates the issue, there is your MCVE. If not, add some of the functionality from your application and see if that recreates the problem. Repeat until you have an example, then post it.

Comment: OK James will do. Thanks

Comment: @James_D i have updated the code and described the problem, its after i .bind canvas with size properties, then it 'covers?' the custom border. my thinking is: that the canvas should be smaller than the actual window ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right it don't answer the question but i have achieved the wanted effect.

I have added a style to the canvas with:

```
canvas.setStyle("-fx-effect: innershadow(gaussian, #039ed3, 2, 1.0, 0, 0);");
```

set up the stage to undecorated:

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

and then created buttons on the scene itself to max/min and close the app, which in fact end up being a better solution.